# Can I make Python use this other program on my PC?

Tags: python, automation

Just learned how to open a file with Python, now is there a way for me to automate what I routinely do with the file (TagAnt)?

I have wordlist.txt on Desktop, and I want Python to

> extract the text from the txt
>
> enter into the **input text** window in TagAnt
>
> then hit **start**
>
> extract the text from **results** window in string form

[image: opened program with Python]

Comment: You need to use a library like [`pyautogui`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) or if you are looking for something more intuitive [atbswp](https://github.com/rmpr/atbswp) disclaimer: I'm the author of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to automate things on your computer saying it to move the mouse to the text zone clicking and putting the text then copying it...